# How to create a custom List from existing List, based on condition in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list

```
 L= [1,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,8,9,9,9].
```

the rule for creating custom list is: current element in the main list `(L)` should be in less-than next number in main list`(L)` .

for example :
In list(L) starts from first element

1) 1 is less than next number 3 in the List `(L)` then add  1 to new list`(new_list)` then remove from main list`(L)`

2) next 3 is not less-than 3 we should skip now (next iteration we have to use  this 3)

3) in current iteration 3 is compared to 4 i.e. 3 less than 4 then add 3 into `(new_list)` and remove from main list`(L).`

4) next compare 4 with next number 4 will not less than  then skip

Like this I want to  create number a custom list which contain list of possible custom lists.

my expected  output after first iteration `in new_list [[1,3,4,5,7,8,9]]` and `L= [3,4,5,9,9]`

my final expected output will be like :`[[1,3,4,5,7,8,9],[3,4,5,9],[9]]`

Comment: could you add, what you tried so far?

Comment: If you can describe the algorithm so accurately, you should be able to turn that into code. What problem are you having?

Comment: Why are the 9 included in your lists ? Because they are not lesser than any number after them so they don't follow any of your rules. Is there a specific rule to include them ?

Comment: if it is final element or last element  we have to add into the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
result = []
while len(L)>0:
    indexes_to_remove = []
    result_temp = []
    L = L_temp
    for i in range(len(L)-1):
        if L[i]<L[i+1]:
            result_temp.append(L[i])
            indexes_to_remove.append(i)
    # Since there is a 9 at the end of each of your list I assume that
    # you add the last value of your list at each iteration
    if len(L)>0:
        result_temp.append(L[len(L)-1])
        indexes_to_remove.append(len(L)-1)
    L_temp = [i for j, i in enumerate(L) if j not in indexes_to_remove]  
    result.append(result_temp)
    print("L = {}; result = {}".format(L, result))
```

---

Output :

```
L = [1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9]; result = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]]
L = [3, 4, 5, 9, 9]; result = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 9]]
L = [9]; result = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 9], [9]]
L = []; result = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 9], [9], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to identify number of custom list I can create from existing list .

Since you only want to identify the number of such lists you obtain at the end, and not the actual list, you can easily compute it as follows. Traverse the list and check for condition less than or equal to and increment the counter, until satisfied, if not satisfies, then reinitialise the counter to zero. And keep traversing. At the end print the maximum value of counter you obtained in any step, which will be the answer.